# Using iconv while maintaining code correctness

Tags: c++, encoding, char, iconv, wchar-t

I'm currently using `iconv` to convert documents with different encodings.

The `iconv()` function has the following prototype:

```
size_t iconv (
  iconv_t cd,
  const char* * inbuf,
  size_t * inbytesleft,
  char* * outbuf,
  size_t * outbytesleft
);
```

So far, I only had to convert buffers of type `char*` but I also realized I could have to convert buffers of type `wchar_t*`. In fact, `iconv` even has a dedicated encoding name `"wchar_t"` for such buffers: this encoding adapts to the operating system settings: that is, on my computers, it refers to UCS-2 on Windows and to UTF-32 on Linux.

But here lies the problem: if I have a buffer of `wchar_t*` I can `reinterpret_cast` it to a buffer of `char*` to use it in `iconv`, but then I face implementation defined behavior: I cannot be sure that the all compilers will behave the same regarding the cast.

What should I do here ?

Comment: In fact, the WCHAR encoding is crucial if you want to translate between the unspecified "system encoding" that you get after `mbstowcs()` and a definite encoding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<char const*>` is safe and not implementation defined, at least not on any real implementations.

The language explicitly allows any object to be reinterpreted as an array of characters and the way you get that array of characters is using `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my thoughts. I assumed converting the `char*` should be safe enough, but I needed to make sure of that.